# Dagger failing to inject Application context

Tags: android, dagger-2

I have dagger set up to manage fragments and viewmodels. I need to pass application context to my view models in order to instantiate and communicate with the repository class. When I try to do this I get an error from dagger stating:

```
    error: [Dagger/DependencyCycle] Found a dependency cycle:
public abstract interface AppComponent {
                ^
      com.example.framework.BaseApplication is injected at
          com.example.di.AppModule.provideAppContext(application)
      com.example.framework.BaseApplication is injected at
          com.example.di.MainViewModelModule.provideMainViewModelFactory(application, �)
      androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.Factory is injected at
          com.example.framework.presentation.common.MainFragmentFactory(viewModelFactory)
      com.example.framework.presentation.common.MainFragmentFactory is injected at
          com.example.framework.presentation.main.MainActivity.fragmentFactory
      com.example.framework.presentation.main.MainActivity is injected at
```

I am new to dagger so I am struggling to identify the root cause of this issue and how to implement a fix. Apologies for the amount of code in this question but dagger has a number of classes where the problem could be.

APP COMPONENT

```
@Component(
    modules = [
        AppModule::class,
        MainViewModelModule::class,
        MainFragmentFactoryModule::class
    ]
 )
 interface AppComponent {

 @Component.Builder
  interface Builder {

      @BindsInstance
      fun application(application: Application): Builder
      fun build(): AppComponent
  }

fun inject(mainActivity: MainActivity)
```

APP MODULE

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@FlowPreview
@Module
object AppModule {

@JvmStatic
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideAppContext(application: BaseApplication): BaseApplication{
    return application
}
```

VIEW MODEL MODULE

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@FlowPreview
@Module
object MainViewModelModule {

@Singleton
@JvmStatic
@Provides
fun provideMainViewModelFactory(
        application: BaseApplication,
        editor: SharedPreferences.Editor,
        sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences
): ViewModelProvider.Factory{
    return MainViewModelFactory(
            application = application,
            editor = editor,
            sharedPreferences = sharedPreferences
    )
}
```

VIEW MODEL FACTORY

```
@FlowPreview
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@Singleton
class MainViewModelFactory
@Inject
constructor(
    private val application: BaseApplication,
    private val editor: SharedPreferences.Editor,
    private val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences
) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {

override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
    return when(modelClass){

        ViewModelUsers::class.java -> {
            ViewModelUsers(
                    application = application,
                    editor = editor,
                    sharedPreferences = sharedPreferences
            ) as T
        }
```

VIEW MODEL

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@FlowPreview
@Singleton
class ViewModelUsers
@Inject
constructor(
        application: BaseApplication,
        private val editor: SharedPreferences.Editor,
        sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences
): ViewModel() {
    private var repoUsers = RepoUsers(application)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Injecting the repository into the viewmodel fixed this issue instead of trying to pass application context through the chain.

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to fix it but the simple way is you should change to `BaseApplication` and remove `AppModule` class because it already provides by `@BindsInstance` annotation

```
@Component(
    modules = [
        MainViewModelModule::class,
        MainFragmentFactoryModule::class
    ]
 )
 interface AppComponent {

 @Component.Builder
  interface Builder {

      @BindsInstance
      fun application(application: BaseApplication): Builder
      fun build(): AppComponent
  }

fun inject(mainActivity: MainActivity)
```

Comment: The app module has all my @provides for all dependencies like room, retrofit, glide etc. I didnt paste all of it in cause it was too big

Comment: so you can only remove provideAppContext function

Comment: Just did that now it gives this error:
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] android.app.Application cannot be provided without an "@Injec"t constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.

Comment: It means you using both Application and BaseApplication in your app. you should choose one of them

Comment: In case you need you both Application and BaseApplication, keep all your code you post change only this method `fun provideAppContext(application: BaseApplication)` to `fun provideAppContext(application: Application)`